# ionic new version break the button design on 2.1.0

Tags: angularjs, sass, ionic2

I recently upgraded the ionic to the latest version of 2.1.0 and the button are coming with out any style and color. I used the primary or danger sass color even it is not working.

My button code looks like this

```
     <button danger>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic keep updating the new changes. There are many breaking changes on latest 2.1.0 version. 
Instead of

```
<button danger>Click </button>
```

Use

```
<button ion-button color=“danger”>Click </button>
```

The color attribute is the new feature of 2.1.0 and it should be passed in the color input on components, not added individually as an attribute on the component.

Reference: [2.0.0-rc.0](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0)